# append line to file and overwrite - python

Tags: python, json, append

How can I append a line to a `json` file and overwrite it with the same name?

```
data.json    
{
 'a': 1,
 'b': 2}
```

I tried

```
with open('data.json', 'r+') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    data.update({'c': 3})
    json.dump(data,json_file)
```

but this appends all the data, not just the intended line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to read the JSON file and pass a second argument in the `json.load()` method, that being to preserve the order of the dictionary. So when assigning a key-value pair to the dictionary, OrderedDict will automatically append it to the end. Finally, write to the file.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    data['c'] = 3

with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. You were right with the `r+` instead of my suggestion for `w`; the former does both writing AND reading.

Comment: I think `dict` have no `append` method because when I run the code with the line `data.append({'c': 3})` it gives me `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`